# adding onclick events to radio buttons in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have the following html

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2">
    <input type="radio" id="RBtest1">Yes</input>
    <input type="radio" id="RBtest2">No</input>
</div>
```

and the following javascript

```
    $('#RBtest1').onclick = function () {
        alert("Test");
        $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
        $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
    };

    $('#RBtest2').onclick = function () {
        $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
        $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
        $('#test').append('test');
    };
```

This javascript fires after page load but yet when I click on the radio buttons nothing happens. Can someone see where I have gone wrong on this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use common name attribute to make them single select:

```
 <input type="radio" name="r1" id="RBtest1">Yes</input>
 <input type="radio" name="r1" id="RBtest2">No</input>
```

**Update:**: the click event doesnt work as you are trying to bind javascript click event to jquery object. You should either use `$('#RBtest1')[0]`,`$('#RBtest2')[0]` to use with javascript click event. Or use jquery click event:

```
 $('#RBtest1').click(function () {
   alert("Test");
   $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
 });

 $('#RBtest2').click(function () {
   $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#test').append('test');
 );
```

Comment: That quite helpful but down the line I will need to add more to the onclick events

Comment: I don't think this answer is related to the question, even though it is correct

Comment: @jgok222: i didnt explained that part because the code looked liked achiving functionality of single click radio button. updated the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery is wrong. Here's a possible fix

```
$('#RBtest1').click(function () {
    alert("Test");
    $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
    $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
});

$('#RBtest2').click(function () {
    $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
    $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
    $('#test').append('test');

});
```

Comment: Yes this is now firing the events however the radio buttons are not changing?

Answer (score 1):

radiobutton have onchange event.

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").on("change", function () {
        var item = this;
        if (item.id == "RBtest2") $('#test').append('test');
        else {$('#test').html("");}
    });

});
```

Example : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/737E9/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need jquery to change the property of radio because radios has that check/uncheck functionalities if you group them with giving same names:

```
<input type="radio" name='ans' id="RBtest1">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name='ans' id="RBtest2">No</input>
```

Try this:

```
$('#RBtest1')[0].onclick = function () {
   alert("Test");
   $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
};

$('#RBtest2')[0].onclick = function () {
   $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#test').append('test');
};
```

---

As we can see you are mixing jQuery and javascript selector and events while you can do this in native js too but jquery is great if you do this way:

```
$('#RBtest1').click(function () {
   alert("Test");
   $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
});

$('#RBtest2').click(function () {
   $('#RBtest2').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#RBtest1').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
   $('#test').append('test');
});
```